# android: setAdapter() not resolved. What to do?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.example.ramya.trailmix;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    }

    String options[] = {"SCHOOL","SHOPPING","RESTAURANT","CUSTOM"};

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_menu,options);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MenuList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

`setAdapter()` is unresolved. When I tried to import `android.app.Activity` and `android.view.Menu`, the statement is ignored. I am completely new to Android studio. How should I fix this? My aim is to display options[] as a `ListView` in the view for this Activity.

Comment: You should Import **ListView** too.

Comment: all of my import statements except the one that imports MenuList are ignored. idk why.

Comment: add you activity_menu.xml layout

Comment: It might be findViewById(R.id.MenuList);

Comment: What happens when you make your `ArrayAdapter` a `ListAdapter`?

Comment: Import statements are not ignored. If they were, you would get a lot more errors than that. What was the *actual* error message?

Comment: Cannot resolve 'setAdapter'

Comment: When I add      `import android.app.Activity; and 
import android.view.Menu;` , android studio automatically adds `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;` and gives the statement _unused import statement_ for the ones I added. I am trying to follow this tutorial : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm

Comment: Surely there was more to it than that? And surely it is obvious that the import for `ListView` was not ignored?

Comment: import for ListView is not ignored

Comment: You cannot instantiate an `ArrayAdapter`, nor call `findViewById()`, nor `ListView#setAdapter()` outside of a class method. Move all of that to `onCreate()`, after the `setContentView()` call.

Comment: You stated above that 'all my import statements except the one that imports `MenuList` are ignored'. Which of these conflicting claims are we to believe?

Answer (score 0):

Move everything to `onCreate()`

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        String options[] = {"SCHOOL","SHOPPING","RESTAURANT","CUSTOM"};

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_menu,options);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MenuList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```